# how can get a specific value from database in using php laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

```php
function subscriptionpack(Request $request)
{
  $sub = subscription::all();
  $details = $sub['details'];
  dump('$details');
}
```

I can get all values from this code, but I can't get the specific field that named details. When  I call `dump($sub`) it was shown all details, but the `dump('$details')` make an error that is **undefined index:details**

anyone can help me to correct this code?

Comment: `$sub = subscription::select('details')->get();`

Comment: It's `dump($details);` without quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select method to select `specific` column data :

```
$sub = subscription::select('details')->get();
```

Or, you can do with on **get()** method as like :

```
$sub = subscription::get(['details']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need single column from the result set use `pluck`

```
$subs = subscription::all();
$details = $subs->pluck('details')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop over to your collection e.g

```
foreach($sub as $s){
     
     dump($s->details)
    
     }
```

or you can try something like.

```
$sub->first()->details
```

but this will give you only first details element from your collection.

Answer (score 0):

First a model should be in singular, no spacing between words, and capitalised.
You should use `Subscription::all();` not `subscription::all();`. You should read [Laravel conventions](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions)

```
use App\Subscription;
..
function subscriptionpack(Request $request)
{
   $sub = Subscription::all()->pluck('details');
   dd($sub);
}
```